# Elasticsearch Range Filter strange behavior for numeric data type like integer, long, double

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, numeric, behavior

I have integer field ranges from 0-100, I am using query filter with gte,lte and gt,lt. The behavior of elasticsearch is very strange when I set the filter 0 - 100 it shows only 1 result and when I set range from 0-99 it gives me correct result (which is 2 in my case).

Even if I set the range from 0-1000 it gives me 0 result set. Firstly, I thought that it is may be due to data type issue since my values(cost) were stored as string but now I have changed the data type to integer but still the range filter is not working properly.

**Search Query**

```
{
"query": {
   "filtered": {
    "filter": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
          "range": {
            "cost": { 
              "gte": 0,
              "lte":100
            }
          }
        },
          {
            "term":{
              "parentId":"6"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you reindex data after changing type to 'integer' ?

Comment: yes I reindexed data after changing type

Comment: Can you post mapping too

Comment: @Duc.Duong I have deleted the index and then added document again and its working like a charm thanks for the help.

Comment: @Duc.Duong the only thing which is bugging me as I am using term in the query and the newly index records are associated with that term only i.e. 6. I have removed all the documents having parentId = 6. But there are others which have different parentId and they were having string as data type. How they are effecting my query ??

Comment: I think after reindex/delete documents, you should do a `flush` action to ensure the changes was committed, no need to delete index. BTW is there anything look strange in ES log file ?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the index (if required)/reindex data will solve the problem.